# How old were you when you (were able to/ could) sing?

Tags: past-tense, questions

what is the most appropriate way to ask this question
How old were you when you **were able to** sing?
How old were you when you **could** sing?
and what is the reason?
Thank you,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those work very well, because, presumably, a person becomes able to sing and then retains that ability for some time. Thus, the way you've phrased it, the answer could be **any time between when the person first learned to sing, and now (or whenever they stopped singing, if applicable).**

It would be more appropriate to ask:
"How old were you when you *first learned how* to sing?"
Or "How old were you when you first became proficient at singing?"

This is because you're more interested in knowing the earliest point in time at which they could sing.